# How to update links on a WordPress website from Google Drive automatically after changing hosts?

Tags: wordpress, web

The basic question is this: existing WordPress with large media library had to move hosts.  All media has been backed up to Google Drive, is there any automated way to update previous posts, so that media can be re-linked directly from Google Drive?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to tag your question with the relevant tags e.g. 'wordpress' here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Describing how the site was moved from the old host to the new host would be useful as it would provide insight into the current state on the new host.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have a complete backup of your WordPress site. This will allow you to easily revert back in case something goes wrong during the update process.

Next, you need to install and activate the Velvet Blues Update URLs plugin.

Upon activation, you need to visit Tools » Update URLs page to configure plugin settings.

Here you need to provide the old and new URLs of your website. After that you need to choose where you want the URLs to be updated.

You can update urls in posts and pages, excerpts, image attachments, custom fields, etc.

Go ahead and select each item that you want to update and then click on the ‘Update URLs Now’ button.

The plugin will find and replace all instances of old URL with your new URL.

You can now visit your website to see that all URLs are updated.

Comment: I pray this works and if it does - I love you and I will donate.

Comment: Alright just did it today - waited from yesterday cause I KNEW this would be a headache - and it's not working. I changed my old address from www.example.com to my cloud storage's address and it still ain't working. What could I be doing wrong? I clicked the box to only change url for media and put in the address of my storage and still no results

Comment: Okay I tried putting my cloud folder into it but that won't work. Is there a plugin that will allow me to do this but also allow me to input a cloud folder so that I can use it?